# FileChooser.ExtensionFilter does not filter .url files

Tags: java, url, javafx, filechooser

I'm using the FileChooser to select a file, and I've added a ExtensionFilter to the FileChooser so that the user is restricted to choosing only the specified file type. In this case I want the restrict the user to selecting .xml files only.

The problem is that my ExtensionFilter allows the user to select not only .xml files, but also .url (internet shortcut) files. The ExtensionFilter does work almost perfect, since no other file types than the two is shown (to my knowledge; I've only tried with the most common file types).

This is my ExtensionFilter:

```
FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extensionFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(
            "XML Files (*.xml)", "*.xml");
```

I tried changing it to allowing only .txt files instead, just to check if it maybe grouped .xml and .url together somehow, but with the same result. The FileChooser then shows both .txt and .url. So it seems that .url files somehow slips through the filtering process.

Is this perhaps a design bug?

Edit: Environment: Windows 8.1 Enterprise + Java 1.8.0_45

**Update: This seems to be an issue that is bound to my environment. All tested environments except mine has failed to reproduce the issue. I managed to reproduce the issue on another computer with the same on environment. Can any one else try this in a Windows 8  environment and confirm the issue?**

Tested environments that isn't able to reproduce the bug:

- `Ubuntu 14.10 with GNOME 3`
- `Mac 10.8.5 + Java 1.8.0_45`
- `Windows 7 Professional SP1 + Java 1.8.0_45`

Here's a SSCCE that reproduces the described issue:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SSCCE extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("SSCCE");

    }

    public SSCCE() {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extensionFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(
                "XML Files (*.xml)", "*.xml");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extensionFilter);

        fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your piece of code. But I can not confirm your bug. I have just tested it and it works fine for me. It could be platform specific.. I tested on Ubuntu 14.10 with GNOME 3.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on `Mac 10.8.5 + Java 1.8.0_45`. Can you add details about your testing environment.

Comment: Strange. My colleague tested my application with the same Java version but on Windows 7, and it worked fine for him as well. Anyhow... I added my environment information.

Comment: Bug confirmed on another computer with the same environment. Check the update in my post.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem (in windows 10) and want to share what I've found:

This bug was reported to OpenJDK and the answer was that this is a Windows issue and would not be fixed.

"Seems the showing of .url file types is a "known issue" in Windows, and there is not a clean or easy workaround for the issue."
"Given that the core of this report is related to unfiltered .url files, and given that is a "feature" of Windows, I am closing this as will not fix."
Source: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8161668